# Target in shortcut: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, windows, cmd, anaconda

I have Anaconda installed, and I want its prompt to open in D:, with admin privileges.
Since "Run as administrator" is enabled, "Start in" option is ignored in Windows.
So I use "Target" to make it open in D:z like this:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /k "D: & cd D:\" /k C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
```

It does open in D:\ but I can't run python from anaconda distribution.
I get this error message:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You have an extra `/k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use `cd /d d:\` and use the variable `%ComSpec%`

```
%ComSpec% /k cd /d d:\ & "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3"
```

Or even:

```
%ComSpec% /k cd /d d:\ & "%programdata%\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "%programdata%\Anaconda3"
```

Comment: Could you please expalin what %ComSpec% and /k are? How to refer to them?

Comment: `%Comspec%` is the environment variable for the path and executable of `cmd.exe` . You can see this by running from `cmd` the line `echo %comspec%` . Then `/k` is a parameter for` cmd` to keep the window open where `/c` will close it after execution, you can see the info by running again from `cmd` `cmd /?`

Comment: So in short. `%comspec% /k` effectively runs `cmd.exe /k` from its location, usually by default `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`

Comment: Specifically, `/k` is a parameter to keep the cmd.exe process running after the command or batch script terminates. There isn't necessarily either a console session or a console-session window involved here (e.g. cmd.exe could be run with the flag `DETACHED_PROCESS` or `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`), and even when there is a console, the command that gets run could spawn a child process that's attached to the console and thus keep the console session alive after cmd.exe and the immediate command/script have terminated.

Comment: @ErykSun Correct, Thanks for the comment.

Comment: `%ComSpec%`, by default, resolves to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe` on modern Windows OS's, but that content is editable. I've seen many PC's with it incorrectly changed to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` thinking that was for running in 64bit mode, and there's nothing to stop a user or application from modifying it to a different console/terminal too. For that reason, and based upon the specific [[tag:cmd]] tag, I'd advise against its use in this case.

Comment: @Compo, yes, the only reason why I used `%ComSpec%` was to shorten OP's `%windir%\System32\cmd.exe` but yes, I agree, `%comspec%` can easily be changed to something dangerous, which I cannot post here for obvious reasons.